# Android webview, login with facebook

Tags: android, facebook, authentication, android-webview

I am developing an android app which is pretty much a Web-view loading an external website. The website requires login with Facebook and everything works great. When I load the app and click the login with Facebook button it takes me to Facebook web for authentication however I have Facebook App installed in my android device. is there a way I can force it to use the Facebook app, not the web?

Comment: remember! the Facebook login button is on the website, since the website is loaded inside web-view on an android app. is it even possible to call android Facebook native app in this situation ?

Answer (score 0):

First check if there is already android app installed on the device or not 
like this:

```
    public boolean checkpackage()
    {
    try{
        ApplicationInfo info = getPackageManager().
                getApplicationInfo("com.facebook.katana", 0 );
        return true;
    } catch( PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e ){
        return false;
    }
    }
```

And then open the app like this:

```
  if(checkpackage())
        {
        startActivity(getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.facebook.katana"));
    }

else{
// open browser
}
```